# Postgres trigger code does not read OLD table record from function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

We have a Postgres database and we want to record when updates change a budget record type. We have a trigger function to record changes to these records called on UPDATE. When we run the update function, the trigger writes records as though every record has been updated from 0 to its current value rather than only firing on changes.

So for instance, if we have a budget value of 20 currently stored and update that to 30 we expect the trigger to fire and report a change from 20 to 30. If we update the value to 20 (ie unchanged) we expect the trigger not to fire. However, in the first case the trigger records an update from 0 to 30 and in the second from 0 to 20.

This only happens when we call the trigger from within the update function. Called using a simple UPDATE TABLE... statement, it responds correctly, not firing in the second case and recording a change from 20 to 30 in the first.

We have tried positioning the trigger both before and after the update and it makes no difference (since a google search suggested there might be a problem with the NEW record if the trigger was called after so we figured let's try either way).

The update function uses an "INSERT things FROM view ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE other things" structure but using identical code in a simple test statement, so outside the function, does not give rise to problems -- the trigger does not fire in the second instance and records 20 to 30 in the first.

Postgres is version 12 and we're in a corporate environment so don't have dba access nor can we upgrade versions.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the full code of the trigger _function_ and the `create trigger` statement for the trigger definition. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: "*when we call the trigger from within the update function*" - and please add the code for that "update function" as well.